# AWS Lambda listen kafka message

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to use Lambda as a Kafka consumer, to be triggered once receive a new Kafka message.
I got a .yaml template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  my-service
  Sample SAM Template for my-service
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
  Api:
    Cors:
      AllowMethods: "'POST, GET, PUT'"
      AllowHeaders: "'*'"
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"
      AllowCredentials: false

Resources:
  ProcessMSKfunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: .
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      MemorySize: 312
      Timeout: 5000
      
      Events:
  MSKEvent:
    Type: MSK
    Properties:
      StartingPosition: LATEST
      Stream: [...]
      Topics:
        - MyTopic
  Policies:
  - AWSLambdaMSKExecutionRole: {}
```

and this Lambda is executing one sample handler

```
let response;

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  // Iterate through keys
  for (let key in event.records) {
    console.log('Key: ', key);
    // Iterate through records
    event.records[key].map((record) => {
      console.log('Record: ', record);
      // Decode base64
      const msg = Buffer.from(record.value, 'base64').toString();
      console.log('Message:', msg);
    });
  }
};
```

but when I try to build, executing the sam build, it is getting error:

> "File "C:...
> ...site-packages\samtranslator\sdk\resource.py",
> line 24, in **init**
> self.type = resource_dict.get("Type") AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'"

Does anyone has a fix alternative for this kind of error?

Comment: `Stream: [...]` isnt this should be a string as per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-msk.html) ? And the error is also saying the same as per [samtranslator](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/blob/develop/samtranslator/sdk/resource.py#L24) code.

Answer (score 0):

> I changed the .yaml file to use Type API and accept "GET" request and now it is working.

```
Events:
        GET:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /test
            Method: GET
```